# Python functional abstraction on Greetings

Tags: python

I'm supposed to get an output for example `greet('Ken','English')` will give me an output of "*Nice to meet you Ken*". However with my code below, it gives me "*Nice to meet you name*".

```
def greet(name, language):
    if language == 'English':
        return 'Nice to meet you ' + ('name')
    elif language == 'Klingon':
        return 'nuqneH ' + ('name')
    else:
         return 'Gi suilon ' + ('name')
```

I'm not sure how to define Name such that it gives me the correct output. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Drop the parens and quotations around name.

Answer (score 0):

lose the brackets and quotes around variable 'name'. I think you can also use 'is' instead of == (for better readability).

```
def greet(name, language):
    if language is 'English':
        return 'Nice to meet you ' + name
    elif language is 'Klingon':
        return 'nuqneH ' + name
    else:
         return 'Gi suilon ' + name
```

Answer (score 0):

'name' is a variable so What you have to do is you need to remove the single quotes of the name variable.
So the final code will look like this -->

```
def greet(name, language):
if language == 'English':
    return 'Nice to meet you ' + (name)
elif language == 'Klingon':
    return 'nuqneH ' + (name)
else:
     return 'Gi suilon ' + (name)
```